# Strange behavior of .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I changed **.bashrc** file on my web server a little bit, to color links on **ls -la** and so on. But when I log in using ssh: ssh user@server and type **ls -al** nothing is coloring, seems like my .bashrc file has not been applied on login. When if I just type **bash** and then again **ls -la** - all works fine. In short, all my rules in .bashrc only apllied when I type **bash** just after authorization, a little boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you log in via ssh, you invoke a *login shell*. When you type `bash` in an existing shell, you invoke an *interactive shell*.

`.bash_profile` is read when a login shell is invoked, and `.bashrc` is read when an interactive shell is invoked.

Try adding this to your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

See `bash(1)` for more details.

Comment: Great answer; however, consulting `man bash` is NOT helpful in this case, because it somewhat misleadingly states that "when executed by the (...) secure shell daemon sshd (...) bash (...) reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`" - which is normally NOT true, because `ssh` creates a _login_ shell by default, as you correctly state in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bashrc` is only read if the shell is interactive and not a login shell:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started,  bash  reads  and  executes  commands  from
>   /etc/bash.bashrc  and  ~/.bashrc,  if these files exist.

Furthermore:

> Bash  attempts to determine when it is being run with [...] sshd.  If bash determines  it  is  being  run  in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if
>   these files exist and are readable.  It will not do this if invoked as sh.

So:

- your remote shell must be `bash`, not `sh`,
- it must not be a login shell, and
- it must be an interactive shell.

Comment: To put this into concrete terms: Since `ssh` creates a _login_ shell by default: in order to create an interactive _non-login_ shell - which then loads `~/.bashrc` - you'd have to invoke `ssh` with `bash -i` as the last argument; e.g.: `ssh jdoe@someHost bash -i`. The 2nd `man bash` quote is (inherently) slightly misleading, unfortunately, because it doesn't make it clear that the behavior described only applies to _non-login_ shells, which are rarely used, given that the `ssh` _client_ defaults to creating _login_ shells.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for the clarifications. I would like to update my quote, but the manpage really doesn't seem to mention that this paragraph applies to non-login shells only...

Comment: Indeed it doesn't: my saying "inherently" was meant to point out that the problem is _with the man page itself_, not in _how you quote it_. My findings are based on trial and error. If you find the same, you could update your answer, or we can just let the comments here speak for themselves.

Comment: Allow me a summary: getting `ssh` and `bash` to directly load `~/.bashrc` is obscure and cumbersome. Sourcing `~/.bashrc` from ~/.bash_profile`, as suggested in @tkocmathla's answer, is a simple solution.